# Star micronics receipt printer image from database

Tags: java, printing, receipt

I have a sm-t300i and im trying to figure out how to print a image from a database. I have the image data but not sure how to plug it in. I have successfuly added a image from the assets but not sure how to from raw image data. Code below is from assets. Also for some reason the image in the code below will not center is there something else i need to do to center the image. Thank you.

```
  AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open("www/img/logo.bmp");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

    StarBitmap starbitmap = new StarBitmap(bm, false, 200);


    commands.add(new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x61, 0x01 }); //align center

    commands.add(starbitmap.getImageEscPosDataForPrinting(false,false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can just convert the base64 and make it a bitmap

```
String imagex = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS  etc";
Bitmap bm = StringToBitMap(imagex);
StarBitmap starbitmap = new StarBitmap(bm, true, 600);
commands.add(starbitmap.getImageEscPosDataForPrinting(false,true));


public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
    try {
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```